# Sending external parameters to Advice in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I need to ensure that a particular method execution time is less than the specified value. I would like to do some thing like the following

```
@Around("execution(* com.foo.bar.executeTask2(..))" + " && someExternalParams(500)")
@Around("execution(* com.foo.bar.executeTask(..))" + " && someExternalParams(5)")
public void checkSLA(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, int maxtime) throws Throwable {

//get staarttime
joinPoint.proceed();
// get endtime

if(endtime - starttime > maxtime)
  System.out.println("Task took longertime");

}
```

How can I achieve this with Spring AOP. One solution is to read the maxtime from file. Any thoughts?

Comment: Since I'm new to AOP I am looking for an example. If you could point me to some resource that would be great. I looked at @args but they are completely for different purpose.

Comment: Where are the parameters coming from?  The caller of the method being proxied?  I would think you can `@Autowired` this configuration into your aspect, since it is Spring managed and all...

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild I want to supply this maxtime limit for a particular task. Yes, It is. I'm using `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`. I intend this piece of code to be part of Logger/Profiler and I do not want to mix this up the business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can make a `@SLA` annotation and read that value from it in your aspect. You must obviously change advise to match that annotation and mark all your methods with `@SLA` annotation.

It's little bit different from your approach but I think it's even better to make annotation for this kind of aspect. This way you don't have to update your pointcut every time you want handling new method. Just add annotation to this method. See example below.

Annotation:

```
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface SLA {
    int maxtime();
}
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public SLAAscpet {
    @Around("execution(@com.foo.bar.SLA * *(..))")
    public void aroundSLAMethod(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        SLA annotation = signature.getMethod().getAnnotation(SLA.class)
        int maxtime = annotation.maxtime()
        ...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
...
@SLA(maxtime=500)
public void someMethodForSLA() {
     ...
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I take the maxtime from a property file. Some thing like this `@SLA(maxtime=${"maxtimeproperty"})`. Can I use `@Value` here? I want the maxtime to be configurable at runtime without redeploying my application.

Answer (score 1):

Your aspect is Spring managed, so I would read from the properties right in my aspect bean.

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Value("${my.system.property.for.max.time}")
    private int maxTime;

    @Around("execution(* com.foo.bar.executeTask(..))")
    public void checkSLA(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        //get staarttime
        joinPoint.proceed();
        // get endtime

        if(endtime - starttime > maxTime)
            System.out.println("Task took longertime");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I have another method `executeTask2()` that needs different SLA how do I do it? I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Is it feasible that you would have a second (or third, or fourth...) advice that could distinguish the acceptable time value?

Comment: I want to make `SLAAspect` a generic one. I like to apply that to any service-method in the system to see it is response time is with in the limits. So I'm looking at a scalable solution. I can have separe adivices but they are identical. So I was wondering if I could make one advice do the job.